# Admin software recommendations for graphic design freelancer/small studio?

Tags: software-recommendation

I'm looking for recommendations for Admin apps/software to use in my small graphic design business. 
I currently use a CRM/Invoicing?Project management system I created in excel but find it time consuming and frustrating when reconciling at the end of month. I'm getting to the stage where I don't mind paying if it's going to save me time and keep things neat.

What system are other freelancers using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using a self-hosted system called [Fusion Invoice](https://www.fusioninvoice.com/) it's been an absolute success (I'm really not affiliated with them). I tried just about all of them to be honest, but this was the only one that provided me with the features I needed in a still simple package. Mostly it automated my monthly billing cycles.

I simply create a "recurring" invoice, set the date, and it's done!

Before that I was basically doing what @Lucian is doing, so I recommend the same solution to him! :)

Comment: Thank Mayersdesign just what I'm looking for - will check it out and let you know how it goes :)

Comment: My pleasure, good luck.

Comment: Do you know if are you able to easily link debits from you bank account (say for stock images or freelancers) to an invoice?

Comment: No it doesn't link to your bank account in any way (I think that's a good thing). It really is just a "design your own highly attractive invoice template", then add customers, and then generate invoices for those customers as PDF's and mail them direct is seconds thing. Plus of course repeat billing in cycles. That really is about it. It adds up and flags the unpaid invoices, so when you "do your books" you simply mark them paid.

Answer (score 0):

I use an InDesign template for my invoices. Not working with many clients, instead have about half a dozen regulars, so mostly reusing previous invoices and just typing in the new date, amount and project name.

Adding 'unpaid' to the INDD file name when issuing and removing this text when paid, to keep track of whats due.